# Incorrect data is saved in UTF-8 DB after user changes encoding in browser

Tags: spring-mvc, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

We have form for creation and edition users.
We have some field in DB for saving user name. This field has UTF-8 encoding.

We have springmvc at the backend side and jsp at the frontend side.
JSP file is in UTF-8 format.

Each page has this code at the top  `<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>`

HEAD tag has `<meta charset="utf-8">` inside.

Attribute `accept-charset = "UTF-8"`( which forces browser to convert data to utf-8 before form submitting ) is set for our form.

When user opens **create user page** and manually changes browser's encoding to  **KOI8-R** and types some username in **Cyrillic** keyboard layout and submits the form.
UserName will be converted to **UTF-8** with `accept-charser` and correct user name will be saved into DB in **UTF-8** format.

After that user opens **edit user page**  and sets browser's encoding to **UTF-8** and sees correct user name in input field.

Then user changes browser encoding to **KOI8-R** and see incorrect user name because browser tries to render user name which is currently in **UTF-8** format in **KOI8-R** and this thing breaks encoding.

Than user tries to submit form with incorrect data and accept-charset cannot convert broken user name to valid **UTF-8** format and incorrect data will be saved into DB.

How can we avoid this situation?

P.S. We can't convert our application to **SPA** using **angularjs** for example which might solve this problem.

Comment: Could You add a hidden field with some uncommon characters?

Comment: I'd found this solution previously. I didn't work for me.